# Mysql - load_file(blob)

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I insert blob to mysql?

load_file("path") doesn't work, because I have always null

Comment: Did you try to Google it? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/

Comment: yeah, I tried google it

Comment: Great, so what you have tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: select load_file('/home/kataz/image/yo.jpg'); has return null, why?